# How to use C# string array with Angular ng-init?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4

I've C# array of string variable, where I just want to populate that in a dropdown box using AngularJS. Can someone help me assigning that to ng-init variable, so that I can ng-repeat the values?

```
@{string[] strArray = new string[length]}

<div ng-init="FieldOptions=@strArray">
   <select class="custom-select-style" ng-options="c as c for c in FieldOptions">   
     <option value="">--@MyResource.Profile.PlsSelect--</option>
   </select>
</div>
```

When I tried like above code snippet, it throws an error "Syntax Error: Token ']' not a primary expression at column 30 of the expression [FieldOptions=[System.String[]]] starting at []]]"

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Showing what resulting HTML you want to achieve *may* allow more people to answer your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works for me:

```
@{
    var options = new string[] { "Option1", "Option2", "Option3" };
    var optionsJson = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(options);
}

<div ng-init="FieldOptions=@(optionsJson)">
    <select ng-model="selectedItem" class="custom-select-style" ng-options="option as option for option in FieldOptions">
        <option value="" selected>(Please select..)</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

However, IMHO, you are approaching the application in the wrong way:

- Data should live in the Angular controller, putting the data in
  ng-init directive is an horrible practice.
- You should not use Razor views, just plain html views. You decided to use Angular, threrefore html is build at the client side, no need to use Razor views that generate html at the server side. By using plain html views, you get an additional advantage for free: views are cached by the browser.

Answer (score 1):

Set your array with parameter like this

```
    string[] strArray1 = new string[length];
    string[] strArray2 = new string[length];
    strArray1.forEach(function (str) {
        strArray2.push({ name: str });
    });
```

In view you can set ng-init and ng-options as below

```
ng-init="FieldOptions=@strArray2"
ng-options="c.name as c.name for c in FieldOptions"
```